# Rails 3 - show all errors for has-one belongs-to models via controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, data-processing

I develop RoR app and i met thing which i can't solve. I have 2 models - **User** and **Teacher**.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :teacher
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher 
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Also i have view with forms for fill data of User and Teacher. After submit data from this form goes in other method of my controller - **create_teacher**. Also i have other method **new_teacher**, in this method i have my view with forms.

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  def new_teacher
    @user = User.new
    teacher = @user.build_teacher
  end

  def create_teacher
    params[:user][:user_role] = "teacher"
    user = User.new(params[:user])

    if user.valid?
      user.save
      teacher = user.build_teacher( params[:user][:teacher_attributes] )
      if teacher.valid?
        teacher.save
        redirect_to admins_users_of_system_path
        flash[:success] = "Teacher created!"
      else
        redirect_to admins_new_teacher_path
        flash[:error] = teacher.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        user.destroy
      end
    else
      redirect_to admins_new_teacher_path
      flash[:error] = user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    end
  end
end
```

My view **new_teacher.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => create_teacher_url, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <%= field_set_tag do %>
    <%= f.fields_for :teacher do |builder| %>
      <div class="control-group">
        <%= builder.label :teacher_last_name, "Last name", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= builder.text_field :teacher_last_name %>
        </div>
      </div>

      ...
    <% end %>


    <div class="control-group">
       <%= f.label :user_login, "Login", :class => "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.text_field :user_login, :value => "" %>
          <%= link_to_function "Generate login", "generate_login()", :class => "btn" %>
        </div>
    </div>
      ...
  <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Create", :class => "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

I have 2 questions:

1) How can i show all errors (for user and teacher)? Is that possible?

2) Is that possible to keep my data in forms when i redirect to **admins_new_teacher_path** from **create_teacher** method?

Comment: If nested forms been used ,please add the code of view. Yes it is possible to show all errors . you have to find objects error on the page

Comment: I added my view, please check my post again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found right solution. For this we should use accepts_nested_attributes_for. Then, when we did this when we create to models

```
user = User.new( params[:user] ) # Using nested attributes in our model
if user.save
   ..
else
   all_errors = user.errors 
end
```

Here we get all errors by `user.errors`.

Answer (score 2):

on the view page you can use `form.object.errors`
Check the code

For form object f use `f.object.errors` in side form
for form object builder `builder.object.errors` in side the nested form

And do a `render :action => :new_teacher` on the controller

To get the object you can write `<%=debug(form.object.errors)%>` as reference

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_teacher
  user_errors, teacher_errors, redirect_path = nil, nil, nil 

  params[:user][:user_role] = "teacher"
  user = User.new(params[:user])

  if user.save
    redirect_path = admins_users_of_system_path
    flash[:success] = "Teacher created!"
  else
    redirect_path = admins_new_teacher_path
    user_errors = user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    teacher_errors = user.teacher.errors.full_messages.to_sentence if user.teacher
  end

  errors_arr = [user_errors, teacher_errors].compact
  flash[:error] = "Errors for user: \n" + errors_arr.join("\n Errors for teacher") if errors_arr.present? 
  redirect_to redirect_path
end
```

Comment: The problem is that `if teacher.valid? ... else ... end` works ONLY if user valid and saved! That means that your version show only errors for user...

Comment: I missed, sorry. It isn't neccessary to use build_teacher, it will be builded automatically as params[:user] has teacher_attributes. user.valid? returns error 'teacher is invalid' if teacher has errors.

Comment: May you edit your code to show what you mean if it's possible? It's a little bit difficult for me to get it...

Answer (score 0):

You could e. g. validate your teacher_last_name field in your model:

```
validate :ensure_teacher_exists

def ensure_teacher_exists
  unless Teacher.find_by_teacher_last_name(teacher_last_name)
    errors.add(:teacher_last_name, "does not exist")
  end
end
```

Then you have to add in your view:

```
<%= builder.error_message_on :teacher_last_name %>
```

This will display the error message near the field.

If you encounter an "undifined method" error add following method to config/initializers/form_builder.rb

```
def error_message_on(attr)
  message = Error.message(object, attr)
  @template.content_tag(:div, message, :class => 'error_message') if message.present?
end
```

Comment: Hm, i tried this and now `undefined method error_message_on for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fa5abb8cad8>`

Comment: Have a look if error_message_on is defined in config/initializers/form_builder.rb. If not, add it as show above.